# ASP.Net MVC Core 2 - Area Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to implement an `Area` for Administrators within my ASP.Net MVC Core 2 application.

I have configured the route for the area as follows:

```
// Default route
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapRoute(
         name: "default",
         template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

// Admin area route
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "admin",
        template: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

This all works pretty well.

This Admin `area` uses the same `Layout` as the main website albeit that the `_ViewStart.cshtml` lives in the `Areas/Admin/Views` directory but this still works fine.

The issue I'm having is with a navigation menu component which lives in the main site layout file and the `href` links in all anchors pointing to the wrong URL when inside the Admin area.

Say I have the following links:

```
<a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Index">My Account</a>
<a asp-controller="Shopping" asp-action="Basket">Shopping Basket</a>
<a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Users">Manage Users</a>
```

When inside the Admin area, the links are now relative to the area and thus appear as if they were as follows:

```
http://localhost/Admin/Account/Index
http://localhost/Admin/Shopping/Basket
http://localhost/Admin/Admin/Users
```

Is there any nice way to make all of these links relative to the site root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple issues how you set things up in your application.

1. You can't use `app.UseMvc()` twice. I think basically the last one will override your first setup. That's why you are seeing all links have `/admin` area prefix.
2. When you want to generate a link to your user management under `admin` area, you should use `asp-area` instead, like `<a asp-area="admin" asp-controller="users" asp-action="index">Manage Users</a>`.

This is how I will setup areas.

#### Setup area route as well as the default route in Startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // The area routing setup has to come before your default routing!
    // Remember the order of these setups is very important!
    // Mvc will use that template as soon as it finds a matching! 

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areaRoute",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=dashboard}/{action=index}/{id?}"
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}"
    );
}
```

#### Setup an admin base controller with [Area] annotation so that you don't have to specify that in all other controllers that should be under the admin area.

```
// Assume you have an Admin area under /Areas/Admin

namespace DL.SO.Web.UI.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("admin")]
    public abstract class AdminControllerBase : Controller
    {
    }
}
```

#### Controllers under admin area

```
// Dashboard controller. I know you have home controller inside 
// your admin area but they should work the same.

namespace DL.SO.Web.UI.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class DashboardController : AdminControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }
    }
}

// Users controller. I know you have User(s) controller but I usually
// just keep the name of the controller singular.

namespace DL.SO.Web.UI.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : AdminControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Specify the area with anchor tag helper

```
// My habit is to always specify the area with the anchor tag helper.
// For public links (those are not under any areas):
//     I just pass empty string, like asp-area=""
// For links pointing to any controller under any area:
//     Just pass the area, like asp-area="admin"

// http://localhost/account
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="account" asp-action="index">My Account</a>

// http://localhost/shopping/basket
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="shopping" asp-action="basket">Shopping Basket</a>

// http://localhost/admin/user
<a asp-area="admin" asp-controller="user" asp-action="index">Manage Users</a>

// http://localhost/admin/dashboard
<a asp-area="admin" asp-controller="dashboard" asp-action="index">Admin Panel</a>
```

Comment: Thank you - your comment was massively helpful. You were correct in the fact that I couldn't use `app.useMvc` more than once however the following does work:

`app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
    
    routes.MapRoute(
     name: "default",
     template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
     name: "admin",
     template: "{area=Admin}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

   });`

Comment: Stay tight. I am showing you how to do it correctly!

Comment: Again, the order of how you setup the routing is important! You can read the comments I put in the coding examples up there.

Comment: Your answer is perfect and works exactly as hoped. I've been implementing it as you've been updating the post but it just works really well. Thank you for that, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the template for the URL to be displayed as preferred. i.e. change to

```
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include the default route. This was already in place in the `Configure` method

Comment: Is it not for the admin section you want to change the route?

Comment: Do I need to add your template suggestion as a route configuration inside the Admin area?