# .NET Core 2.1 adds area as url parameter

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I'm trying to implement an Area for Administrators within my ASP.Net MVC Core 2.1 application.

I have configured the route for the area as follows:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areas",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

In _Layout.cshtml I have:

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index">Admin</a>
```

In AdminController I have:

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Razor is generating wrong URL not like http://localhost:44327/Admin/Admin/Index but https://localhost:44327/Admin?area=Admin.

Comment: What if you only call UseMvc once and move both MapRoute calls into it?

Comment: Thank you. You were correct when I moved both Map Routes in UseMvc method everything works normal.

Comment: Great clarification for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50377260/9868648).